# Select parent div attribute in a for generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select an attribute in a parent div, but no luck so far.

The HTML:

```
<div class="build">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="craft shop" qnt="1"></div>
    <div class="craft shop" qnt="5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
var ITEMS = [
{
  "item":"shop",
  "prefix":"custom",
  "icon": "shop",
  "type": "shop"}];

for (var i = 0; i < ITEMS.length; i++)
{
  var items = ITEMS[i];
  var quantity = $(".craft." + items['item']).attr("qnt");
  $(".craft." + items['item']).html
  ('<a class="item-block item-' + items['type'] + '" href="' + items['prefix'] + '-' + items['item'] + '.html">'+
   '<i class="' + items['icon'] + '"></i>' +
   '<span class="name" data-i18n="' + items['item'] + '">' + items['item'] + '</span>'+
   '<span class="qnt">x' + quantity +'</span>'+
   '</a>')};
```

So when I use `<div class="craft shop" qnt="1"></div>` it generates this:

```
<div class="craft shop" qnt="1">
  <a class="item-block item-shop" href="custom-shop.html">
    <i class="shop"></i><span class="name" data-i18n="shop">shop</span>
    <span class="qnt">x1</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="craft shop" qnt="5">
  <a class="item-block item-shop" href="custom-shop.html">
    <i class="shop"></i><span class="name" data-i18n="shop">shop</span>
    <span class="qnt">x5</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I am trying to display the quantity from the attribute "qnt", but I am having problems to select it.
See how the second block uses the same qunatity of the first one?

I already tried:

```
var quantity = $(this).parent().parent().attr("qnt");
```

and it didn't worked.

Example in codepen: https://codepen.io/RHenri/pen/BWNVpw

Comment: Where did you use `var quantity = $(this).parent().parent().attr("qnt");`? What didn't worked means?

Comment: Use jquery data() api like data-qty instead of adding a custom a qty attribute and use closest() instead of parent()

Comment: I tried to use that instead of how I am selecting it now, and it didn't worked.

Do you mean like this: `var quantity = $(this).closest().attr("data-qnt");`?
It didn't worked too.

Comment: @RogerHN, your code is weird. You say you use `var quantity = $(this).parent().parent().attr("qnt");` but in your code there is no such thing. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ionut what do you mean? It's all described there... Instead of using: `` var quantity = $(".craft." + items['item']).attr("qnt"); I tried `var quantity = $(this).parent().parent().attr("qnt");`

Comment: @RogerHN, that's not how `$(this)` works.

Comment: @Ionut I am accepting suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need a another loop to select a particular instance at time. So that you can apply quantity and other values based on that particular div.

You are using $(".craft." + items['item']).attr("qty") to get value of qty attribute from a div which always return first div that match that class name. And then you again using that name to set html to all div which added same html content to all matching div with that particular name. 
To get valve from each div and add html accordingly you need another loop to go through all element that are selected by a particular class name.

For this i am using [$.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Try this.

```js
var ITEMS = [{
  "item": "shop",
  "prefix": "custom",
  "icon": "shop",
  "type": "shop"
}];

for (var i = 0; i < ITEMS.length; i++) {
  var items = ITEMS[i];
  var quantity = $(".craft." + items['item']).data("qnt");
  
  $(".craft." + items['item']).each(function(i, v) {
    var quantity = $(this).data("qnt");
    $(this).html('<a class="item-block item-' + items['type'] + '" href="' + items['prefix'] + '-' + items['item'] + '.html">' +
      '<i class="' + items['icon'] + '"></i>' +
      '<span class="name" data-i18n="' + items['item'] + '">' + items['item'] + '</span>' +
      '<span class="qnt">x' + quantity + '</span>' +
      '</a>')

  });
};
```

```css
.item-list .item-block,
.build .item-block {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.item-list .items .item-block i,
.build .items .item-block i {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-size: contain;
  float: left;
}

.item-list .item-block .name,
.build .item-block .name {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Microsoft YaHei;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 135px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-list .items .item-block i,
.build .items .item-block i {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-size: contain;
  float: left;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}

.item-list .item-block .qnt,
.build .item-block .qnt {
  line-height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Microsoft YaHei;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
}

.item-shop {
  background-color: #1e7ea9;
}

.shop {
  background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/64/shop-icon.png);
  background-color: #25a9ae;
}

.craft {
  background-image: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="build">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="craft shop" data-qnt="1"></div>
    <div class="craft shop" data-qnt="5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't thinked that I need another loop.  Can you explain to me how this works: `function(i, v)` why the "v" letter there too?

Comment: function(i, v) v is current element in loop and i is the index of that element. For more take a look at https://api.jquery.com/each/